# Orders grid, display [ deleted ] in Purchased from (store)

Tags: orders, magento-1.6, order-grid

I removed some stores and now when I see the dropdown "Purchased from (store)" in `Sales -> Orders ->Grid` I found the `deleted` option. I remove every relationship between the stores deleted and orders but the  `deleted`  option still shown.

Someone knows how to remove this option?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove that deleted filter option by rewriting Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::_prepareColumns

If you look at the addColumn used for the store_id, you'll see that the display_deleted parameter is set to true. Just set it to false.

I don't know what it's used for though, since Magento won't let you deleted orders, right?

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question was about orders from deleted stores, not deleted orders. But it looks like you found the right parameter